Flutter Hive when try to get List<T> Hive V4 throws 'Type Mismatch' error
I have tried to make module from Hive with Generic models. Created 'CacheModel' mixin like this:
mixin CacheModel {
  String get id;

  CacheModel fromDynamicJson(dynamic json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson();
}

And a manager to registerAdapters like this:
final class HiveCacheManager extends CacheManager {
  HiveCacheManager({super.path});

  @override
  Future<void> init({required List<CacheModel> cacheModels}) async {
    final documentPath =
        path ?? (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    Hive.defaultDirectory = documentPath;

    for (final cacheModel in cacheModels) {
      Hive.registerAdapter(
          '${cacheModel.runtimeType}', cacheModel.fromDynamicJson);
    }
  }

  @override
  void remove() {
    Hive.deleteAllBoxesFromDisk();
  }
}


CacheManager is an abstract class and have a CacheOperation abstract class like this:
abstract class CacheOperation<T extends CacheModel> {
  void add(T item);
  void addAll(List<T> items);
  void remove(String id);

  void clear();
  List<T> getAll();
  T? get(String id);
  T? getFirst();
}

I also have a HiveCacheOperation which extends CacheOperation of T Type like this:
final class HiveCacheOperation<T extends CacheModel> extends CacheOperation<T> {
  HiveCacheOperation() {
    _box = Hive.box<T>(name: T.toString());
  }

  late final Box<T> _box;
  @override
  void add(T item) {
    _box.put(item.id, item);
  }

  @override
  void addAll(List<T> items) {
   
    _box.putAll(Map.fromIterable(
      items,
      key: (element) => (element as T).id,
      value: (element) => (element as T),
    ));
   
  }

  @override
  void clear() {
    _box.clear();
  }

  @override
  T? get(String id) {
    return _box.get(id);
  }

  @override
  T? getFirst() {
    return _box.get(_box.keys.first);
  }

  bool countBoxKeys() {
    if (_box.isOpen) {
      final count = _box.getAll(_box.keys).cast<T>().isNotEmpty;

      return count;
    }

    return false;
  }

  @override
  List<T> getAll() {
    return _box
        .getAll(_box.keys)
        .where((element) => element != null)
        .cast<T>()
        .toList();
  }

  @override
  void remove(String id) {
    _box.delete(id);
  }
}

I created a UserCacheModel and extend it from CacheModel like this:
final class UserCacheModel with CacheModel {
  UserCacheModel({
    required this.user,
  });

  UserCacheModel.empty() : user = const UserModel();

  final UserModel user;

  @override
  CacheModel fromDynamicJson(json) {
    final mapCast = json as Map<String, dynamic>?;
    if (mapCast == null) return this;

    return copyWith(userModel: UserModel.fromJson(mapCast));
  }

  @override
  String get id => user.id.toString();

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return user.toJson();
  }

  UserCacheModel copyWith({UserModel? userModel}) {
    return UserCacheModel(user: userModel ?? user);
  }
}

Finally created a ProductCache which required CacheManager like this:
final class ProductCache {
  ProductCache({required CacheManager cacheManager})
      : _cacheManager = cacheManager;

  final CacheManager _cacheManager;

  Future<void> init() async {
    await _cacheManager.init(
      cacheModels: [
        CorporationCacheModel(corporation: const CorporationModel()),
        UserCacheModel(user: const UserModel()),
      ],
    );
  }

  late final HiveCacheOperation<UserCacheModel> userCacheOperation =
      HiveCacheOperation<UserCacheModel>();

  late final HiveCacheOperation<CorporationCacheModel>
      corporationCacheOperation = HiveCacheOperation<CorporationCacheModel>();

}

But when i try to call .getAll function of userCacheOperation i got "Invalid argument(s): Type mismatch. Expected UserCacheModel but got CorporationCacheModel.".
So is this a registerAdapter error or something else?
